# Quartz Scheduler NOT STARTED. In standby mode

Tags: spring, maven, quartz-scheduler, mode, standby

Having not luck using the Quartz Scheduler. Any and all help would be much appreciated! I assure you have all the required dependencies in my pom.

Here's my spring-config.xml.

```
<bean id="testObject" class="test.Test"/>

<bean id="jobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
    <property name="targetObject" ref="testObject"/>
    <property name="targetMethod" value="print"/>
</bean>

<bean id="simpleTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SimpleTriggerFactoryBean">
    <!-- see the example of method invoking job above -->
    <property name="jobDetail" ref="jobDetail"/>

    <property name="startDelay" value="1000"/> 

    <property name="repeatInterval" value="5000"/>
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" >
    <property name="jobDetails">
        <list>
            <ref bean="jobDetail" />
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="simpleTrigger"/>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="autoStartup" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

And here's my Test class... very simple.

```
  package test;

  public class Test {
       public Test(){};

       public void print(){System.out.println("asdfasdfasdf!!!!!\n\n\n\n");}
  }
```

And the output is this...

15:11:46.550 [main] INFO  org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler - Scheduler                 meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.1.7)     'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean#0' with instanceId 'NON_CLUSTERED'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 10 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore' - which does not support persistence. and is not clustered.

Answer (score -1):

I should've shown the rest of the xml file. There was an other bean in the file with an init-method that was preventing the quartz scheduler from starting.